# Add flags to Alpine.js UI - dynamic class name

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I'm trying to add:

https://github.com/lipis/flag-icon-css

to my app so that when someone clicks on a mapbox country I can show the flag

Is there a way that you would recommend how to do this?

I tried the following but I get `TypeError: (void 0) is undefined`

```html
<span class="flag-icon" x-bind:class="{ [`flag-icon-${$store.ui.clicked.flag}`]: true }">
    <h3 class="pt-3 mb-3 ml-5 text-lg " x-text="$store.ui.clicked.name">Country / City name</h3>
</span>
```

```js
Spruce.store('ui', {
    clicked: {
        name: 'Welcome!',
        u: 'US',
        flag: (this.region_ident ?? this.u).toLowerCase().slice(0, 2),
    },
})
```

edit: inside my on map click function I have this:

```
    Spruce.store('ui').clicked = {
        ...Spruce.store('ui').clicked,
        city: e.features[0].properties,
        name,
    }
```

Maybe I could try:

```
$el.addClass(`flag-icon-${$store.ui.clicked.flag}`)
```

But I am not sure where to put that.

This works but I think an Alpine.js solution would be more succinct.

```js
    document.getElementById('flag-show-bottom').removeAttribute('class')
    document
        .getElementById('flag-show-bottom')
        .classList.add(
            'flag-icon',
            `flag-icon-${e.features[0].properties.u.toLowerCase().slice(0, 2)}`,
        )
```

Comment: Do you have the full code for the relevant functionality? Off the top of my head I would double check that the relevant Alpine.js component is subscribed to the Spruce store.

Comment: inside my on map click function I have this:

```
    Spruce.store('ui').clicked = {
        ...Spruce.store('ui').clicked,
        city: e.features[0].properties,
        name,
    }
```

Comment: oh it should be this.city.region_ident

Comment: I guess `:class` only adds classes and doesn't remove them

Comment: `:class` should add and remove classes, latest issue I've seen about this in the repository is https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine/issues/374

Comment: It looks like I'd need to make a key for each flag value so that it could evaluate to false to be removed. I guess I'll keep my flags outside of Alpine.js for now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured it out. `x-bind:` takes an expression. You can use it on anything. it is really versatile. You don't have to use `:class={ className: bool }` format.

You can just use strings:

```
<img src="../images/blank.gif" 
x-bind:class="`flag ${ $store.ui.clicked.country 
    ? 'flag-' + $store.ui.clicked.country.region_ident.toLowerCase().slice(0, 2)
    : $store.ui.clicked.city 
    ? 'flag-' + $store.ui.clicked.city.u.toLowerCase().slice(0, 2)
    : '' }`" />
```

(I switched to using a different flag library but the logic is the same)